# Built-in functions in Excel Online are in a different language from the user interface

Tags: localization, excel-online

Previously I was using my Microsoft account in Turkish, but I set to English a few years ago. All applications were working as expected until I tried the built-in functions in Excel Online.

For example, I cannot use the `SUM()` function, but its Turkish equivalent `TOPLA()`. I tried to set the language again and cleaned up the cookies as suggested on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256129/how-do-i-change-the-menu-language-of-excel-online/33274508), it didn't change the built-in functions. Maybe it only changes the UI language, which was already in English.

Even the arguments (e.g. `number1`) are shown in English, but the function name is in Turkish.

[image: excel online]

Is there a different setting for the language of built-in functions, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- log in to your OneDrive account
- go to **https://account.microsoft.com/profile/**
- select **Edit country/region**
- choose your preference
- when done, change the global language on the bottom left
- **[Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx)** formulas should be now in your preferred language

[image: 0]

Comment: It works perfectly after cleaning the browser cache.